# Pointer to next address

Tags: c++, pointers, cout

When you run the code like this it shows the value of d -> 4
If you uncomment the cout<<&a it shows the proper value of a -> 1

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4;
    /*cout<<&a<<endl;
    cout<<&b<<endl;
    cout<<&c<<endl;
    cout<<&d<<endl;*/
    cout<<*(&b - 0x1);
}
```

Can somebody help me understand why does the cout changes the returned value?

Comment: This is undefined behavior, so anything can happen.

Comment: Since this is a guess I am putting it here: I would have to say the variables are getting optimized away since you are not using them so you invoke undefined behavior as `a` no longer exists.

Comment: I agree with NathanOliver. Are you sure the `4` is coming from `d`? You are very likely just grabbing some value off the stack. Try changing the value of `d` to something else and see if the printed value is still 4. Ultimately, relying too much on the compiler placing things in the stack in a specific order is risky unless you know your compiler very, very well. Especially for something like this, which is undefined, as interjay pointed out.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do something like this?

Comment: The variables are not guaranteed to be contiguous in memory.  The variables could be in registers and registers on most CPUs don't have addresses.  Thus some of the undefined behavior.

Comment: Even `&b - 0x1` (without dereferencing) is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Without this statement

```
cout<<&a<<endl;
```

variable `a` is not used in the program. So the compiler is allowed to generate the object code such a way that the definition of `a` will not be included in the program.

When you uncomment this statement variable `a` is present in the object code.

Take into account that in general the program behaviour is undefined.

You may not dereference pointer before a variable if it is not a part of an array.

```
cout<<*(&b - 0x1);
```

Moreover the order in which the compiler places variables in the memory is unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking undefined behaviour.

It isn't valid to perform modify a pointer like this unless it's part of any array and your arithmetic keeps the value within the array (or one past the end of it).

So you're accessing some arbitrary area of memory and there's no definition of what you might get back.

When you comment out those lines the optimizer is probably noticing you don't use `a`,`c` or `d` and so omits them from the code. When you leave them in you get the outcome you expect because you've correctly inferred where your compiler (though by no means all compilers) store `a` relative to `b` (if at all).

The optimizer isn't required and generally won't try to infer that your accessing of `&b-0x01` happens to land on `a`. It's undefined behaviour and so irrelevant what outcome you get.

Answer (score 0):

By definition C++ would allocate all addresses next to each other starting from the last,  unless the memory is used.  In all my experience they are next to each other. The only reason I can see is because of the optimization a is not allocated if it isn't used.
It always shows the value of d, which is the strangest part.